# how to create draggable toggle button in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I want to create a toggle button that can be clicked and also dragged (progressively) from

side to side.

I have seen some tutorials, but I think all of them enable clicking only.

How should I approach this?

I want to support Android 2.3

so I cannot use native "switch"

Comment: Do you mean Switches?

Comment: I want to support Android 2.3

so I cannot use native "switch"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For API Level 14+ you can show Switch, that will come with a nice transaction on switching, and for lower version you can just use a CheckBox with drawable to make it look like a Switch, only thing missing below ICS is the animation on transaction, if you can afford that.

You will need to create seperate layout folder for that called `layout-v14` and put ICS+ files in it. You can create a layout file in this folder called my_widget.xml . So your structure may look like

- layout

  - your_layout.xml
  - my_widget.xml
- layout-v14

  - my_widget.xml

and you can include it like `<include layout="@layout/widget" />`.From your Activity/Fragment, you can access it like:

```
int version = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (version >= 14) {
    // use switch view
}
else {
    // use checkbox
}
```

Otherwise there is also a library you can download from [Here](https://github.com/BoD/android-switch-backport). I have not tested it yet, but it claims to have backported Switch to Android 2.1+.

Comment: but it's not dragabble

Comment: It is draggable. See the demo here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.sample